# Complex dielectric constant in ultraviolet range

Tags: semiconductor-physics, dielectric

Dielectric constant of a material could be a complex number, which is dependent of the frequency of electromagnetic wave. From the Springer material website, I learn that both the real part and imaginary part of dielectric constant of bismuth telluride becomes very small when the electromagnetic wave energy is around 10eV. Here is the website:
http://www.springermaterials.com/docs/info/10681727_963.html

However, that website doesn't provide the dielectric constant when the energy of electromagnetic wave is higher than 12eV. Here is my question, how will the real and imaginary part of dielectric constant change when the energy of electromagnetic wave is higher and higher? Will they approach to a certain limit? If so, what's the limit?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I will answer the question by myself.

In ultraviolet range, dielectric constants tend to approach 1. The real part is very close to one, and the imaginary part is very close to 0.

reference:
David Attwood, Soft X-Rays and Extreme Ultraviolet Radiation: Principles and Applications.